# How to recompile ntl and gmp libraries with "-fPIC" flag & make HELib as a shared library & undefined reference to func(std::ostream&) error

Tags: build, compilation, shared-libraries, gmp, ntl

[image: the Image for nm -CD /usr/local/lib libfhe.so]

a C++ code built into a shared library for HELib is using NTL and GMP static library. But it gets following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(FFT.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value 
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It was suggested int the post Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440140/jni-build-shared-library-using-static-ntl-library)

to recompile NTL and GMP with "-fPIC " flags.
I'am not able to find how I should do that.

Edit:

I'm able to build the shared library now after :
recompiling GMP and NTL by:
    `./configure --enable-shared`
for gmp and 
     `./configure SHARED=on`

After make Install of HELib. I get error when I run the example codes.
The link to the Makefile : [click to see makefile](https://github.com/ibarrond/Pyfhel/blob/master/Pyfhel/.Makefiles/Makefile_HElib)

Error:

> g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -pthread -DFHE_THREADS -DFHE_BOOT_THREADS -DFHE_DCRT_THREADS -o Test_General_x Test_General.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lntl -lgmp -lm -lfhe
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to `write_raw_int(std::ostream&, long, long)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to`read_raw_ZZ(std::istream&, NTL::ZZ&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to `void write_raw_vector<long>(std::ostream&, std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> > const&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to`writeEyeCatcher(std::ostream&, char const*)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to `write_raw_xdouble(std::ostream&, NTL::xdouble)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to`read_ntl_vec_long(std::istream&, NTL::Vec&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to `void read_raw_vector<long>(std::istream&, std::vector<long, std::allocator<long> >&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to`readEyeCatcher(std::istream&, char const*)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to `read_raw_int(std::istream&, long)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to`read_raw_xdouble(std::istream&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to `write_raw_ZZ(std::ostream&, NTL::ZZ const&)'
>   /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so: undefined reference to`write_ntl_vec_long(std::ostream&, NTL::Vec const&, long)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:179: recipe for target 'Test_General_x' failed
>   make: *** [Test_General_x] Error 1

Comment: Why are you linking a dynamic library with a static one? Other than that, please read some doc, even `.../configure --help` gives the answer...

Comment: Because I'm writing a python wrapper module for the shared library's example code (HELib) and HELib library is dependent on the Libraries GMP and NTL.   I tried adding     ./configure SHARED=on  for NTL and ./configure --enable-shared for GMP but I'am still getting the same error that I got before recompiling it to a shared library.

Comment: If you are getting the same error, it may be that you have several versions of the lib and it isn't picking the right one. Also, I wonder on what system you are that you need to compile GMP/NTL yourself. Anyway, to answer your question, for GMP, try `./configure --help | grep -i pic`.

Comment: Thank you, as you said ,  "it may be that you have several versions of the lib and it isn't picking the right one." this was the case.

Comment: Since all your link errors involve istream/ostream and you are using C++11, I suspect an incompatible ABI. Did you compile HElib with the same compiler and options as the example? `nm -CD /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so` and see what looks closest to those undefined references.

Comment: yes i compiled HELib also with the same compiler and the same options.  Please check the image attached, all undefined references are prefixed by U, sorry but i do not understand why.  thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by incompatible ABI? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc Glisse provided the answer for the first two parts of the question.For the third part "Undefined Reference error" the answer is I'd not compiled and linked a x.cpp containing the functions that caused the undefined reference into my shared library. hence check : nm -CD /usr/local/lib/libfhe.so to see if these functions are listed with a linking address or not. If not then check which code provides this functionality. Link that code to the shared library.

Answer (score 1):

For NTL v11.5.1 atleast, doing `./configure --help | grep -i pic` (as suggested in one of the comments for GMP) did not help at all - it found no matches. However, making a one line change in the file `ntl-11.5.1/src/DoConfig` (on line 17) from:

```
'CXXFLAGS'    => '-g -O2'
```

to:

```
'CXXFLAGS'    => '-g -O2 -fPIC',
```

solved the problem for me.